# How can I map Keys on my keyboard to new symbols?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

My laptop's keyboard wastefully contains two Keys for the dash that both produce the too short `-`. I need longer dashes. So how can I map or force these 2 Keys to produce [different dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash) of my chosen input?

Comment: [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily fixable with a 3rd party program called Sharpkeys. Sharpkeys requires Microsoft .NET framework 4.0 or more.

You can install Sharpkeys from their website [here](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

After that, you can map one of your old keys to the new one :

[image: Key mapping with Sharpkeys]